# LEFT or FULL JOIN with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, associations

I have 5 models: user, keyword, question, association and question_status.

- User and Keyword are related by association (same keyword can be
  added by multiple users & vice-versa)
- Keyword and Question are related by has_many belongs_to (a keyword
  can have many questions and a question belongs to a keyword)
- User and Question are related by question_status (a user can tag
  questions as answered, deleted etc.)

So the relationships are:

1. A user has many keywords through associations
2. A keyword has many users through associations
3. Keyword has many questions
4. Questions belong to a keyword
5. An user can put status on many questions through question_status
6. A question can be assigned status by many users through question_status

I had to build 5 models since same keyword can be added by multiple users. So I had to keep users and keywords separate from each other and have them related through association. Also multiple users can have different tags (answered, deleted, archived etc.) on the same question. So I have to maintain this statuses separately from questions table.

Models are -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :keywords, :through => :associations

  has_many :question_statuses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, :through => :question_statuses

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :associations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :associations

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword

  has_many :question_statuses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :question_statuses

class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword
  belongs_to :user

class QuestionStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
```

I need to create a JOIN query in ActiveRecord that will give me questions for a user (e.g. users.id = 2) for keywords that the user has added in his account excluding the questions that have deleted or answered e.g. deleted = t or answered = t in question_statuses table.

A record gets added to question_statuses only when an user tags a question. Otherwise, question_statuses wouldn't have any records for that user.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You mention deleted = t and answered = t. Are those boolean fields in Rails? If you are using explicit text fields instead of boolean fields I'd recommend switching to using boolean fields so that Rails understands what type of information you intend to store in them.

Comment: They are boolean fields.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Answer replaced based on feedback from OP

Here's the ActiveRecord syntax that I think should do it:

```
Question.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN question_statuses ON question.id = question_statuses.question_id AND question_statuses.user_id = #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(user_id)}").where(question_statuses: {user_id: nil})
```

That's equivalent to the SQL:

```
SELECT * from questions LEFT OUTER JOIN question_statuses ON question.id = question_statuses.question_id AND question_statuses.user_id = 2 WHERE question_statuses.user_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: this would create an inner join, but I think I need a left join or full join, since question_statuses don't have any records for a user unless that user tags a question as answered or deleted. Questions are shown for a user from questions table based on the keywords that they have in their list. How can I do a left join in your answer?

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly what you want is ALL questions for which the user hasn't set any status?

Comment: You are right, but your answer assumes that question_statuses contain all the questions irrespective if the user tags it or not. If that was the case, then your solution would work. Your solution results in the following `SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" INNER JOIN "question_statuses" ON "questions"."id" = "question_statuses"."question_id" WHERE "question_statuses"."user_id" = 2` Questions form an inner join with question_statuses, but question_statuses wouldn't have anything if the user has not tagged any questions. The questions are shown to the user from the questions table.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll have to edit my answer to take that structure into account.

Comment: I was not able to make it work even with a LEFT OUTER JOIN, not sure why! I was able to get the results with the following SQL. But not sure how to write it in ActiveRecord. `select questions.* from questions LEFT JOIN question_statuses ON questions.id = question_statuses.question_id where questions.id NOT IN (select question_id from question_statuses where question_statuses.deleted = 't')`

Comment: I need to try your revised answer, for now I am using a NOT IN clause to get all questions except in question_statuses.

Comment: Good luck. By the way, my query should also perform better than a NOT IN with a subselect.

Comment: BTW, here's some more info on ANTI JOIN (which is roughly what you want here: http://blog.montmere.com/2010/12/08/the-anti-join-all-values-from-table1-where-not-in-table2/

Answer (score -1):

2 approaches

**1.Using Table Names**

```
Question.join(question_statuses: :users).where('users.id = 2').where('question_statuses.deleted is true').where('question_statuses.answered is true')
```

**2.Using AREL**

The join would be the same as above, but the where clauses would be different slightly, you may need to play around in script/consoles

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. In the answer above, you meant question_statuses.deleted is false, since I need to exclude them. Similar for answered. Right?

Comment: @user2376032 - I think this would not work unless I do a left join since question_statuses would have only those records that have been tagged by user as deleted or answered. If the user has not tagged any questions yet, the query above will return zero records since its doing an INNER JOIN with question_statuses. Any idea how to do a LEFT JOIN?